# counting results within a if/else statement

Tags: php, count, sum

I am trying to sum the total results in an if/else statement. so the $result (in there for example) would appear 4 times. I have tried count($result), this doesnt work.

```
while ($sq=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

if ($avg > $btmspeed && $avg < $topspeed){
    $result; 

}else{  
}
}
```

Basically I am running a while loop through some database results and these existing variables would give 4 results through the if statement and I want to reflect that. I know its probably and easy answer but banging head against a wall and search engines havent given me the answer. please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter. 
    Var i=1; 
Outside of the loop.

Inside the loop add:

```
i++;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, as commented above, I just need it to count how many results i have the i++ gives a 1234 output

Comment: while ($sq=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$totalmill = $sq['TTOP']; // total milliseconds student took on this page
$seconds = $totalmill / 1000; // turned into seconds
$words =$sq['TVWP']; // total words on this page
$sec = $words / $read; // what the average reading speed this page should be
$avg = $words / $seconds; // average reading speed the student took
$totpage = mysql_num_rows($query); // total number of pages calc for overall comprehension



if ($avg > $btmspeed && $avg < $topspeed){
 $result; 

}else{ 
}

Comment: Outside of the while loop put:

Comment: $iterator = 0; then after $result put $iterator++;

Comment: tried that produces "1234" all i want it to do is count the results and display "4" i.e. this produce 4 results

Comment: I assure you it doesn't. If youre getting 4 results back for $result, $iterator is going to equal 3.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8369/discussion-between-ken-wheeler-and-meohmy)

Comment: $iterator=0; while ($sq=mysql_fetch_array($query)){ $totalmill = $sq['TTOP']; // total milliseconds student took on this page $seconds = $totalmill / 1000; // turned into seconds $words =$sq['TVWP']; // total words on this page $sec = $words / $read; // what the average reading speed this page should be $avg = $words / $seconds; // average reading speed the student took $totpage = mysql_num_rows($query); // total number of pages calc for overall comprehension if ($avg > $btmspeed && $avg < $topspeed){ $result; $iterator++; }else{  } echo $iterator;

Comment: I think we all got thrown off by you using the count(). If you want to get the sum, build an array in the if condition and use array_sum to add them

Comment: thanks to ken the legend, code he last put works and movinf the $iterator outside the loop did the trick! thanks to all for your help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to move the $result declaration outside the loop and increment it inside the 'if' block?

```
$result = 0
# loop starts here
if ($avg > $btmspeed && $avg < $topspeed){

   $result = $result + 1

} else{


}
```

Comment: thanks for the response! however, i need to just count how many results it produces so as this would produce 4 results just need a piece of code that would count the results and display the number 4

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your result is a number. You would loop over whatever it is I assume an array with information, where you'd be checking the if-else like you originally provided.

```
$i = 0;
for($x=0; $x < $result; $x++;)
{
   if ($avg > $btmspeed && $avg < $topspeed){

     $i++;

   }else{


   }
}
echo $i;
```

Comment: thanks for this, but all i really need to know is how many results are being displayed, I dont think there is need for an array but its possible. i am just starring at the screen at the minute!

Comment: alter your orignal post to show what the data is for $result then that your trying to get the count of and or display per constraint met.. so we can better understand what your asking :-D